# Unable to login at Github from Chrome/Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, github

I can login on my Github account from Firefox as normal. But when I try to log on in Chrome, I got the following error:
[image: error screenshot]

Happens on Windows and Ubuntu. What can I do?

[EDIT, UPDATE]

Here I left a screenshot of the console:

[image: console screenshot]

Not only happens on my account.

Comment: Disable the "Allow-control-allow-origin" plugin

Comment: I don't have such plugin

Comment: what about any other plugins?

Comment: I only have LiveReloader (that I should uninstall bcs I don't use it) and referer control.

Comment: I think you need to disable referer control plugin. that should work !

Comment: @OnlyMAJ Thanks!! that worked. Didn't know this plugin would cause this...

Comment: @GermanRobayo i had same problem already . happy to hear that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable Referer control plugin. that should fix the issue !

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue and then disabled "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" extensions in chrome then it's working fine.